# Generated classes not found

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

Using Dagger2 and Kotlin, my component class implementations are not being generated when other calling code exists. When no calling code exists, the implementations are generated.

E.g.

```
val comp = DaggerMyComponent.create()
```

Causes the build to fail, `DaggerMyComponent` is not generated and thus cannot be found

```
// val comp = DaggerMyComponent.create()
```

The `DaggerMyComponent` class is generate and can be viewed on disk, the build succeeds.

I've tried Dagger 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1-Snapshot, using Kotlin beta-1103.
I can post my gradle file, source code, or stack trace if needed.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your app's build file, make sure you added

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

some example projects can be found here

https://github.com/damianpetla/kotlin-dagger-example/tree/master/app
https://github.com/burntcookie90/KotlinDaggerDataBinding